# Java 14 javax.net.ssl.SSLException occurs only on some computers with identical cacerts files

Tags: java, java-14, sslexception, cacerts

I have a Java 14 application where some computers throw a javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException or javax.net.ssl.SSLException when trying to access https://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov/cgi-bin/filter_gfs_1p00.pl. It works fine for me, and all computers are using the same Windows 10 jre (that I built with jlink) and the same cacerts that came from OpenJDK 14. As I do not have the issue, I am unable to reproduce and debug. I have tried getting a user to replacing the cacerts on one of the computers, and it made no difference. Also, pasting the same URL direct into Chrome works. I have not tried exporting the cert from Windows and reimporting into cacerts, as my cacerts works and I don't see how that would make a difference, unless every cacerts is computer specific which does not appear to be the case from the modification date.

Any ideas on what could be causing this, and why Java is throwing the exception.

Comment: Does the exception message _say_ "path building failed" or something else? Do you have a stacktrace, especially any 'caused by' part? Does `keytool -printcert -sslserver nomads.ncep.noaa.gov` show the correct certs (issued by GoDaddy)? Can you have the application and/or user set sysprop `javax.net.debug=ssl:handshake` and capture the (large) output?

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED. The particular users had not updated the jre, only the jar file and it was missing the jdk.crypto module.